# How to check if an app of specified package name is running in a device or not as I want to trigger an activity everytime the app is launced

Tags: java, android

I am developing an app in  which I have created a service .In that service I want to keep checking every min if a specified package name app is runnning or not! If it is,this trigger a message.
My Main Question is how to create a function which checks if the specified app is running or not. I checked through the below listed code but It doesnt give any information. Please Help me!

I've tried this code!

```
boolean found=false;
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningAppProcessInfo = am.getRunningAppProcesses();

for (int i = 0; i < runningAppProcessInfo.size(); i++) {
  if (runningAppProcessInfo.get(i).processName.equals("com.example.pubganti_addci")) {
        found=true;
    }
}

if(found) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Not Running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

It works only when I use My package's Name! 
Please Help me!

Comment: what version of android have you tried this on? The new privacy policy states that you should not be able to do such things, for security reasons.

Comment: For me it seemed the code included in the post didn't build in Android Studio.  I changed it by adding a seemingly needed cast just before trying to interpret the process name, got rid of the "if" and had it create a list of all data returned and placed it in the toast.  Only the one app. showed up.  To expand a bit upon what has already been mentioned, if you examine the documentation on the ActivityManager and related classes, you can see that a variety of types of information returned, are said to pertain to the particular process or app.  In some other cases, permissions are needed.

Comment: `getRunningAppProcesses` will only able to get the current app process since API 21, you should not do that for other apps. if you want to monitor your other apps, you can, for example, send a broadcast when it opened (for security reason, you should add permission check for the broadcast receiver)